# Customized .bst file for bold and italics et. al. not working

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, harvard-style, bst

I am using overleaf to write a document. I uploaded a custom .bst file in my overleaf project of `agsm` referencing style. I needed the 'et. al.' to be in bold and italic. I tried to do so by editing all the `et~al.` in the agsm .bst file to `\textbf{\textit{et~al.}}`. When compiled, the italics worked, but the bold part did not. Need help.

My preamble:

```
\ProvidesPackage{preamble}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
%\usepackage{enumerate} % not along with enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{booktabs,floatrow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\bibname}}
%Page Layout
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    %total={170mm,257mm},
    left=0.7in,
    right=0.7in,
    top=1in,
}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
%Modifying Headings
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{\MakeUppercase\@chapapp\ \thechapter}{1pt}{\LARGE}
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{0pt}
\usepackage[english=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
%Paragraph and line spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%Header Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

%Image

%\graphicspath{{C:\Users\TAMOGHNA\Desktop\latex}}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushright}
\let\originalepigraph\epigraph 
\renewcommand\epigraph[2]{\originalepigraph{\textit{#1}}{\textsc{#2}}}

%To insert blank page
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \mbox{}%
    \clearpage}

%ToC Name Change
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

%LoT, LoT Name change
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}}

%nomenclature
\makenomenclature

%Table formatting array
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\floatsetup[table]{objectset=centering,capposition=top}

%---------------------------------------------------------%
%Appendices
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\appendixname{APPENDIX}}
%---------------------------------------------------------%
%Acronyms
%Acronyms

%---------------------------------------------------------%
%Slash Frac 
\usepackage{xfrac}
```

My main body:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{preamble}
\usepackage{import}
%---------------------------------------------------------%
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}
\import{titlematter/}{frontpage.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%---------------------------------------------------------%
%ToC
\tableofcontents


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\import{./}{introduction.tex}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{agsm_IB}
\bibliography{irbref}
\end{document}
```

This is a large document, so I am writing each chapter in individual tex files.

Comment: Maybe boldface is deactivated in the bibliography, in the bst or in the document class. Hard to tell from the information you provide. Please add a small document, starting with `\documentclass` to your question, such that we see your context and can experiment  with it.

Comment: @gernot boldface works fine in the main text. The problem exists only in the best file. In any case, I will edit my post and add some context to it.

Comment: It would appear that your document loads (at least) three separate and mutually incompatible citation management packages: `cite`, `natbib`, and `apalike`. This cannot possibly end well. Please simplify your preamble to eliminate all stuff that's immaterial to the query you've posted. And, by all means, please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico I do see the problem you have addressed and I have corrected it. I have kept only ```natbib``` package. However, It did not resolve my issue.